# Number of ways to choose 5 balls from groups of indistinguishable objects of the same color

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are **5 blue, 5 green and 3 red balls.** (balls of the same color are **indistinguishable**)
How many ways are there to choose 5 balls?

I can't seem to find an answer to this question. I tried doing ${13 \choose 5}$ but that would overcount many possibilities. Is there any easy way to solve this?

Comment: You want to find the number of solutions of the equation $b + g + r = 5$ in the nonnegative integers subject to the restriction that $r \leq 3$.  Without that restriction, this would be a [combination with repetitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) problem.

Comment: Please clarify whether the order in which the balls are chosen matter ? The word "ways" in your question leads to this ambiguity.

Comment: The order does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b$ be the number of blue balls drawn.
Let $g$ be the number of green balls drawn.
Let $r$ be the number of red balls drawn.

As noted in the comments by [N.F. Taussig](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/173070/n-f-taussig), you want to find the number of solutions to the equation $b + g + r = 5$ with the restriction that $b \le 5, g \le 5$ and $r \le 3$. The first $2$ conditions are redundant as they will always hold for the equation. To do this you can use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). The total number of solutions will be

$${5 + 3 - 1 \choose 3-1} = 21$$

We now subtract the number of solutions for which $r \ge 4$. We have

$$1 + 0 + 4 = 5, \; 0 + 1 + 4 = 5, \; 0 + 0 + 5 = 5 \longrightarrow \; \text{3 solutions}$$

Your answer hence is

$$21 - 3 = \boxed{18}$$

While this method worked for your problem, let's try to find a more general solution.

> There are $b$ blue, $g$ green and $r$ red balls. How many ways are there to choose $n$ balls?

The answer to this question will be the number of solutions to

$$x + y + z = n, \; x \le b, \, y \le g, \, z \le r$$

The question is equivalent to asking for the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $$(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ... + x^b)(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ... + x^g)(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ... + x^r) \tag{1}$$

This is true because of the property

$$x^p \cdot x^q = x^{p + q}$$

where $p + q$ denotes a unique solution to an equation involving the sum of $2$ variables. Every time a unique solution is achieved the coefficient increases by $1$ as $x^{p+q} + x^{p+q} = 2x^{p + q}$.

To now find the coefficient of $x^n$, we first convert $(1)$ to a simpler form using geometric series.

We get

$$(1) = \frac{1 - x^{b + 1}}{1-x}\cdot\frac{1 - x^{g + 1}}{1-x}\cdot\frac{1 - x^{r + 1}}{1-x} = (1 - x^{b + 1})(1 - x^{g + 1})(1 - x^{r + 1})(1 - x)^{-3}$$
$$= (1-x^{b + g + r + 3} + x^{b + g + 2} + x^{b + r + 2} - x^{b + 1} + x^{g + r + 2} - x^{g + 1} - x^{r + 1})(1 + 3x + 6x^2 + 10x^3 + \, ... \, + {n + 2 \choose n}x^n + \, ...)$$

The coefficient of $x^n$ hence is

$${n + 2\choose n} - {n + 2 - (b + g + r + 3)\choose n - (b + g + r + 3)} + {n + 2 - (b + g + 2)\choose n - (b + g + 2)} + {n + 2 - (b + r + 2)\choose n - (b + r + 2)} - {n + 2 - (b + 1)\choose n - (b + 1)} + {n + 2 - (g + r + 2)\choose n - (g + r + 2)} - {n + 2 - (g + 1)\choose n - (g + 1)} - {n + 2 - (r + 1)\choose n - (r + 1)}$$
$$= {n + 2\choose n} - {n - b - g - r - 1\choose n - b - g - r - 3} + {n - b - g\choose n - b - g - 2} + {n - b - r\choose n - b - r - 2} - {n - b + 1\choose n - b - 1} + {n - g - r\choose n - g - r - 2} - {n - g + 1\choose n - g - 1} - {n - r + 1\choose n - r - 1}$$
$$= \boxed{{n + 2\choose n} - {n - b - g - r - 1\choose n - b - g - r - 3} + {n - b - g\choose n - b - g - 2} + \sum_{b, g} {n - b - r \choose n - b - r - 2} - \sum_{b, g, r}{n - b + 1\choose n - b - 1}}$$

Answer (score 1):

If, as you have clarified, order does not matter, you can imagine that the *balls* are identical, and being put in blue, green and red *boxes.* We then use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) with correction for the restriction on red.

Without the restriction on red, the answer would be $\binom{5+3-1}{3-1} = \binom72= 21$

From this we subtract $1$ way with all $5$  in red box, and $2$ ways with $4$ in red box and one in blue or green box to give a final answer of $21-1-2=18$