# Is there an Intuitive approach to finding the number of non-negative integer solutions to $a_0 + \dots + a_k = n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Let $n$, $k$ be integers with $k \geq 1$, and $n \geq 0$. Let $S_k(n)$ be the number of  integer solutions $a_0, \dots, a_k$ with each $a_i \geq 0$ to the equation. Then it can be shown that $S_k(n) = \binom{n+k}{k}$.

For example, if we let $S_k(n)$ be the number of solutions to this equation, then it is easy to see that

$$
 S_0(n) = 1 = \binom{n}{0}, \quad S_1(n) = n+1 = \binom{n+1}{1}, \quad S_2(n) = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2} = \binom{n+2}{2}. 
$$

The proof, which I have provided a sketch of below, that I know for this result is an unenlightening proof by induction. Whenever I see a result involving binomial coefficients, there is often an intuitive way to prove it by some sort of "counting" argument. However, I have not yet stumbled across one for this result. Is anyone aware of a nice intuitive counting approach to this?

---

By partitioning the set of solutions to the equation by the value of a chosen $a_i = t$ say, one arrives at the relationship
$$S_{k}(n) = \sum_{t=0}^{n} S_{k-1}(n).$$
Using this relationship, induction on k reduces the result to proving the summation formula
$$\sum_{t=0}^{n} \binom{k+t}{k} = \binom{n + (k+1)}{k+1}.$$
This summation formula is easy to prove by induction on $n$ using Pascal's binomial relationship
$$\binom{n+1}{k+1} = \binom{n}{k+1} + \binom{n}{k}.$$

Comment: The usual [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#:~:text=In%20the%20context%20of%20combinatorial,his%20classic%20book%20on%20probability.) argument is intuitive, I'd say.

Comment: Yep, not sure why I didn't see that. Thank you. If you put that as answer I'll accept it.

Comment: It is the difficult problem called **partitions of a number**. (see, in particular, Ramanujan's congruences).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an equation $a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_k = n$, the number of solutions is the same as the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of

$$\underbrace{(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ... + x^n)(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ... + x^n)...(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ... + x^n)}_{k + 1 \; \text{times}} \tag{1}$$

This is true because of the property

$$x^p \cdot x^q = x^{p + q}$$

where $p + q$ denotes a unique solution to an equation involving the sum of $2$ variables. Every time a unique solution is achieved the coefficient increases by $1$ as $x^{p+q} + x^{p+q} = 2x^{p + q}$.

To find the coefficient of $x^n$, we can convert $(1)$ to a simpler form using geometric series.

We get

$$(1) = (1 - x^{n+1})^{k+1}(1 - x)^{-k-1}$$

We can ignore the $(1 - x^{n+1})^{k+1}$ term as it will yield powers higher than $x^n$.

The coefficient of $x^n$ hence is

$${n + k \choose k}$$

This technique is more powerful than the standard stars and bars approach because we can also place bounds on each of the variables. For example, if we have $a_0 + a_1 = n$ for $r\le a_0\le s$ and $p \le a_1 \le q$, the number of solutions will simply be the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of

$$(x^r + x^{r + 1} + x^{r + 2} + ... + x^s)(x^p + x^{p + 1} + x^{p + 2} + ... + x^q)$$

I have applied this method to solve a combinatorics problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4461105/1044958).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: consider $b_i=a_i+1$. This is a bijection between the set of nonnegative integer vectors $a$ with $\sum_{i=0}^k a_i=n$ and the set of positive integer vectors $b$ with $\sum_{i=0}^k b_i=n+k+1$.

Step 2: Interpret this new problem as inserting $k$ bars into the $n+k$ gaps between $n+k+1$ stars, so there are ${n+k \choose k}$ ways to do it.